# Calling a function of an Object that takes a function as its parameter

Tags: swift, function

Say I have the following code:

```
import Foundation

enum Operation {
    case BinaryOperation ((Double, Double) -> Double)
}

var multiply = Operation.BinaryOperation({$0 * $1})

//Error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'Operation'
multiply(3.0,2.0)
```

How would I call the function multiply here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is the associated value of an enum value, so you have to extract it first before calling it.  One way to do that is to use pattern matching:

```
if case let .BinaryOperation(function) = multiply {
    function(3.0, 2.0)
}
```

This can also be written as:

```
if case .BinaryOperation(let function) = multiply {
    function(3.0, 2.0)
}
```